# Error while autoinstalling gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad

Tags: software-installation, totem, gstreamer

I am trying to install two packages on my Totem Media Player in order to play .asx files: `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` and `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad (i386)`. The application has its own installer, but when I play the "Install" button, nothing happens.

So my question is, how could I install the two packages by an alternative method? I am running Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem got solved with the help of @budman7 from the [Linux Forums](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/207685-error-while-installing-gstreamer1-0-plugins-bad-totem-movie-player-post979779.html?highlight=#post979779). This is what had to be done:

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager
2. Search for `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`
3. Proceed to install it. Now, the installer wants to remove a set of i386 packages. i386 refers to a 32-bit OS, and since I am running a 64-bit one, I agree to the removal.

Finally, I am able to play .asx files with Totem Media Player!

Answer (score 0):

---

This will install 'totem' and all dependencies :

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install totem` http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/totem

---

Comment: Hi there, @Knud! Unfortunately, that didn't help. I already had Totem Media Player installed on my system (it comes in default with Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I think), and what exactly happens is that when I am trying to open an .asx file with my Totem, it opens this small box saying: 

> Searching for multimedia plugins: Videos requires to install plugins to support the following multimedia feature: Microsoft Media Server (MMS) protocol source

Shortly after, it changes into another box, which goes:

> Install extra multimedia plugins?

Comment: The latter one is the autoinstaller I mentioned before. It offers two plug-ins to be installed: `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` and `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad (i386)`. Neither the autoinstaller or the command you gave works, though...

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress in solving the problem, but unfortunately I still cannot play the .asx file on my Totem Media Player. This is what I did:

1. I opened Ubuntu Software **Center**, which was the old version that still came in default in Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. **Note:** This is not the same as GNOME Software a.k.a. Ubuntu Software, that is nowadays the default application manager in Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS!
2. I searched for `GStreamer plugins for mms, wavpack, quicktime, musepack` and installed it. Now when trying to open the .asx file, the automatic installer is only asking to install `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad (i386)`. And now actually, the automatic installer actually works!

Well, now the both packages seem to be installed. However, when opening the .asx file, nothing still happens. Any thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: **UPDATE:** Weird, I just noticed that when I try to open the .asx file again, the Totem Media Player opens the automatic installer and is suggesting to install the ` gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad (i386)` package again ... even though I witnessed the installation of the packages with my own eyes last time!

Comment: **UPDATE:** According to Synaptic Package Manager, also `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:i386` is already installed on the system. I tried re-installing it, but it didn't help.

Now, I noticed that a package called `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` is not installed. If I try to install it, the installer says that the following packages should be removed: **`gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:i386`**, `libmjpegutils-2.1-0:i386`, `libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0:i386`, `libmplex2-2.1-0:i386`, and `libsrtp0:i386`. In turn, it wants to install `libmjpegutils-2.1-0`, `libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0`, `libmplex2-2.1-0`, and `libsrp0`. Ideas..?